# Get all methods via controllers in my apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When I use:

```
var assemblies = GetAssemblies();
IEnumerable<Type> controllers =
      assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ControllerBase))));

foreach (var controller in controllers)
{
     var methods = controller.GetMethods();
     foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
     {
          var returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType;
     }
}
```

I get standard methods ("CreatedAtAction") and not controllers of my application like ("MyControllerName").

Comment: What is the `assemblies` variable?

Comment: @MatteoUmili 
var assemblies = GetAssemblies();

Comment: How is `GetAssemblies()` implemented?

Comment: @MatteoUmili assemblies all applications in my repo

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

```
var methods = controller.GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpMethodAttribute), true).Length > 0);
```